# How to select data from two different table with same column name in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join

Hello please refer my following code which is in model

```
public function common_report($where) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('collect_data_form_history_db as ch');
    $this->db->join('board_artwork_history_db as bh','bh.shop_id = ch.shop_id');
    $this->db->where('bh.shop_id', $where);
    // $this->db->where('bh.shop_id',$where);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

what i want is all data from both table collect_data_form_history_db and board_artwork_history_db.
I get the data but in the wrong format.
In table 'collect_data_form_history_db ' i have 11 entries and in board_artwork_history_db i have 18 entries.
so data I get should be 29 rows but I get 198 rows means 11 * 18.
please tell me the solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to use left join for that. Try this way

```
$this->db->join('board_artwork_history_db as bh','bh.shop_id = ch.shop_id', 'left');
```

Comment: I have tired it but it gives same result

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->db->select('t1.*, t2.*')
          ->from('collect_data_form_history_db t1, board_artwork_history_db t2')
          ->where('t1.shop_id = t2.shop_id')
          ->where('t2.shop_id', $where);

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Gives same result

Comment: attached sample data table

Answer (score 0):

Try full outer join

```
public function common_report($where) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('collect_data_form_history_db as ch');
    $this->db->join('board_artwork_history_db as bh','bh.shop_id = ch.shop_id', 'full outer');
    $this->db->where('bh.shop_id', $where);
    // $this->db->where('bh.shop_id',$where);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Tired your solution but gives same result

Comment: try to use union in sql
`$this->db->query('SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name1 UNION SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name2')->result();`